for the vscode action "go to references", can I remove imports from showing up?
I want to reduce my cognitive load when looking at these references, and not be bothered to check the import references. IntelliJ products seems to have this feature.

What language(s)? I'm not sure if this might be different between them.

You have to edit the question and reveal the programming language you are talking about, because this feature is controlled by language servers, not VS Code itself.
